# Next.js + Axios: Pages with server-side rendering throw 404 in console but still get data properly from API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, axios

Currently I am working on a Project in Next.js with Axios to pull data from the backend. The issue I seem to be running into is that for some reason, while my pages with server-side rendering(through getStaticProps())seem to be functioning properly, they take longer than I would expect to render and I get two errors on loading them.

The first error is a generic Axios "Request failed with status code 404" in the server console. The data fetched from the backend is properly being sent to the page though.

The second error is "Failed to load static props" in the browser console.

This is baffling me, because I can't figure where I could be having an API request 404'ing and the client-side error message doesn't give me any meaningful data to go off of.

Things I've tried: Changing how I retrieve the API URL, adding a check for the data and returning { notFound: true } if data is null/undefined, and console.log() to try and trace where the failing request might be coming from. So far I've come up empty.

Update: I also have tried explicitly declaring types for the data being passed to the page component, and have double- and triple-checked my API URLs and the data being returned and nothing jumps out as erroneous. I am still stumped. For now it's not a big problem as this doesn't appear to affect functionality aside from slightly slower page loads, but I would still appreciate any help solving it!

My code:

```js
const Page = ({ results }) => {
  const stuff = results.stuff;

  ...
};

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({ req }) => {
  const apiURL = `http://localhost:3000/api${req.url}`;
  const { data } = await axios.get(apiURL);

  if (!data) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    }
  }

  return {
    props: {
      results: data.data,
    }
  };
};
```

All SSR pages have the same getServerSideProps() method.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're running into two separate issues. The 404 error indicates that the URL you're trying to fetch from doesn't exist. Double-check that your apiURL in getServerSideProps is correct.

The "Failed to load static props" error suggests an issue with the data returned from Axios. Make sure it's what you expect and can be correctly passed as props.

Lastly, consider better error handling. If data is null or undefined, you're returning { notFound: true }, which causes Next.js to render a 404 page. You might want to handle this differently, like returning an error message or redirecting to another page.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So, my API URL is as expected, and like I said, the data is correctly retrieved from the database and sent to the page component. That data is simply a JavaScript Object retrieved via Prisma.findUnique(), and should be fine to pass to the page props, but I will have to dig further into the docs to be certain.

Comment: Hmm, Have you tried to keep an eye on your network tab in the dev tools? A pesky API request might be going AWOL, causing that annoying 404.

Even if your data looks good on the surface, it's possible that something's missing when you least expect it. Ensure you're not counting on a property that sometimes isn't there. You might want to play it safe by adding checks or defaults before sending off your props from getServerSideProps.

Also, don't forget about your old pal, the try-catch block, especially when you're dealing with axios.get. It's like a safety net.